# Title bootstrap not correctly printed on smartphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am developing my own website/application but I have a display problem on a title.
The web browser edge is in foreground and hide my title (Please, look at the picture with red rectangle to understand). The source code is bellow. I am doing something wrong ? I am using Bootstrap. Should I add CSS ?

```
<body>
    <div id="divformulaire">
        <h3>HERE IS MY PROBLEM:</h3>
      <form method="post" action="requetes/creerMission.php" role="form" id="formulaire">
          <hr/>
            <input class="form-control" id="nothing1" name="nothing1" type="text" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing2" name="nothing2" type="text" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing3" type="number" name="nothing3" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing4" type="text" name="nothing4" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing5" type="text" name="nothing5" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
            <input class="form-control" id="nothing6" type="number" name="nothing6" placeholder="Nothing" required>
            <hr/>
            <span class="label label-default">Nothing</span>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nothing7" type="text" name="nothing7">
                <option>Non</option>
                <option>Oui</option>
            </select>
            <hr/>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annonce">Nothing</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="nothing8" name="nothing8" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="create" type="submit">Nothing</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

[Title problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h10z.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your div with the id of #divformulaire doesn't have any margin on the top. If you want the title to always be visible, you need to offset the entire div by roughly the amount of the browser topbar, where the URL is.

```css
#divformulaire {
margin-top: 50px}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="divformulaire">
        <h3>HERE IS MY PROBLEM:</h3>
      <form method="post" action="requetes/creerMission.php" role="form" id="formulaire">
          <hr/>
            <input class="form-control" id="nothing1" name="nothing1" type="text" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing2" name="nothing2" type="text" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing3" type="number" name="nothing3" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing4" type="text" name="nothing4" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
          <input class="form-control" id="nothing5" type="text" name="nothing5" placeholder="Nothing" required>
          <hr/>
            <input class="form-control" id="nothing6" type="number" name="nothing6" placeholder="Nothing" required>
            <hr/>
            <span class="label label-default">Nothing</span>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nothing7" type="text" name="nothing7">
                <option>Non</option>
                <option>Oui</option>
            </select>
            <hr/>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annonce">Nothing</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="nothing8" name="nothing8" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="create" type="submit">Nothing</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```